# Xamarin iOS Binding project doesn't seem to include the library or interface definitions

Tags: c#, objective-c, binding, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I have created an iOS binding project, add my static library which created the following linkwith.cs content with some added frameworks and linker flags I need

```
[assembly: LinkWith ("libMyLibrary-iOS.a", LinkTarget.ArmV7 | LinkTarget.ArmV7s | LinkTarget.Simulator,Frameworks = "CoreTelephony SystemConfiguration UIKit Foundation CoreGraphics", LinkerFlags = "-ObjC -all_load -lz -lstdc++", ForceLoad = true )]
```

In the ApiDefinition.cs file I copied what tthe Objective-Sharpie created with some corrections and addition that missed. Also moved all enums to the StructsAndEnums.cs.

I noticed something strange too, intelisense is not working for some attributes, specifically BaseType and Static are red and not recognized, with the enums in the StructsAndEnums.cs file. Build is successful the second time, if I clean and try to build I get error in the autogenerated file or if I try to rebuild I get the error always, second build is fine.

The static library file is 12.5MB but the result .dll release build is only 4kb which I find really strange, and since it's not the first binding library I create I know that the .a library should be merged into the .dll library.

Checking the build action of the files looks correct.

libMyLibrary-iOS.a -> ObjcBindingNativeLibrary

ApiDefinition.cs -> ObjcBindingDefinition

StructsAndEnums.cs -> ObjcBindingCoreSource

No project properties are modified or added, just new binding project of Xamarin Studio 5.3 (build 441).

In the solution I created a single view application, added the binding project library as a reference but there is no namespace visible to use the interface contracts.

Are there any actions I could take to resolve or debug the issue?

**[EDIT]**

The compile error I get when rebuilding the project is about a block I set like this

```
public delegate string SPLJSONModelKeyMapBlock (string keyName);
```

and use it in this interface

```
    [BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
    public partial interface SPLJSONKeyMapper {

        [Export ("JSONToModelKeyBlock")]
        SPLJSONModelKeyMapBlock JSONToModelKeyBlock { get; }

        [Export ("modelToJSONKeyBlock")]
        SPLJSONModelKeyMapBlock ModelToJSONKeyBlock { get; }

        [Export ("initWithJSONToModelBlock:modelToJSONBlock:")]
        IntPtr Constructor (SPLJSONModelKeyMapBlock toModel, SPLJSONModelKeyMapBlock toJSON);

        [Export ("initWithDictionary:")]
        IntPtr Constructor (NSDictionary map);

        [Static, Export ("mapperFromUnderscoreCaseToCamelCase")]
        SPLJSONKeyMapper MapperFromUnderscoreCaseToCamelCase { get; }

        [Static, Export ("mapperFromUpperCaseToLowerCase")]
        SPLJSONKeyMapper MapperFromUpperCaseToLowerCase { get; }
    }
```

A screenshot of the errors in `Trampolines.g.cs`

[image: Compile error in autogenerated Trampoline.g.cs]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

Try returning `NSString` from the delegate instead of string:

```
public delegate NSString SPLJSONModelKeyMapBlock (string keyName);
```

**First answer**

It looks like the second rebuild isn't done correctly (if it fails the first time it should fail the second).

In other words you need to fix (or report to us) the build errors you're getting in the autogenerated files.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, edited the question with all appropriate information.

Comment: YES! It worked nicely, hmmm, I should check when to use the iOS types to C# types. Any link that I might miss or never seen?

Comment: This is a bug on our end, we should automatically do the NSString -> string translation.

Comment: Great, thanks for the update Rolf. Can we monitor the issue reported somewhere or an ETA to the fix, e.g. next Xamarin iOS release?

Comment: Hi guys! I see the answer is marked as solution, but I can't see actually the answer to the question "why the library is empty". I am experiencing a similar issue: everything compiles (builds) well, but the output library is just 1KB and no namespace visible in iOS project. Any help?

Comment: Oh, actually, the generated library size is 1MB (*.dll), but it's still not accessible in main iOS project.

Comment: After some playing with that, it appeared a very strange issue. It does work well when selecting a Debug mode of the parent project, but the referenced library still is not accessible in Release(!). Even though the library itself was build in Release! So weird!